# method not working inside addactionlister

Tags: java, actionlistener

I am trying to build a LAN communication software where the process should be like this, when the user is logged in then networking between the client and server should start.

The problem that I am facing is that whenever I put my startRunning()(this is the method that starts the networking) method inside the addactionlistener of the button the whole software freezes but if I put the method outside of addactionlistener the networking starts fine. The problem is in the btnNewButton.addActionListener .If the count is 1 then it should call the startrunning() method which it doesn't and the whole software freezes.

Every method starting from the startRunning() method to down below is working perfectly.The database is also capable of checking whether the given username and password is correct or not. This software runs well when the startRunning method is in the constructor but not inside the btnNewButton.addActionListener.

```
     public class Server extends JFrame {

private JTextField userText;
private JTextArea chatWindow;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection;

Connection dbconnection = null;

private JTextField textField_1;
private JPasswordField passwordField_1;



public Server() {

    super("Communication system");

    dbconnection = sqliteConnection.dbConnector();

    setupFrame();


}

private void setupFrame() {
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("UserName");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 11, 81, 14);
    getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Password");
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(10, 36, 59, 14);
    getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Login");

    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try {
                String query = "SELECT * FROM EmplyeeInfo WHERE Username=? and password=?";
                PreparedStatement pst = dbconnection
                        .prepareStatement(query);

                pst.setString(1, textField_1.getText());
                pst.setString(2, passwordField_1.getText());

                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                int count = 0;
                while (rs.next()) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (count == 1) {

                    textField_1.setText("");
                    passwordField_1.setText("");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Correct Username and Password");
                    startRunning();

                } else {
                    textField_1.setText("");
                    passwordField_1.setText("");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong try again");
                }
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
        }
    });

    btnNewButton.setBounds(335, 7, 89, 23);
    getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBounds(101, 8, 224, 20);
    getContentPane().add(textField_1);

    passwordField_1 = new JPasswordField();
    passwordField_1.setBounds(101, 33, 224, 20);
    getContentPane().add(passwordField_1);

    userText = new JTextField();
    userText.setBounds(10, 230, 330, 20);
    userText.setEditable(false);
    userText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
            userText.setText("");
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(userText);
    userText.setColumns(10);

    chatWindow = new JTextArea();
    chatWindow.setBounds(10, 75, 330, 144);
    getContentPane().add(chatWindow);
    setVisible(true);
}

// set up and run the server
public void startRunning() {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100);

        while (true) {
            try {
                waitForConnection();
                setupStreams();
                whileChatting();
            } catch (EOFException eofException) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                showMessage("\nServer Ended the conection!");
            } finally {
                closeCrap();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// wait for the connection, then display connection

private void waitForConnection() throws IOException {
    showMessage("Waiting for someone to connect... \n");
    connection = server.accept();
    showMessage(" Now connected to "
            + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
}

// get stream to send and receive data
private void setupStreams() throws IOException {
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    showMessage("\n Streams are now Setup \n");
}

// during the chat conversation
private void whileChatting() throws IOException {
    String message = " You are now connected";
    sendMessage(message);
    ableToType(true);

    do {
        // have a conversation
        try {
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            showMessage("\n" + message);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
            showMessage("\n I don't know what the user send");
        }

    } while (!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));
}

// closing the streams and sockets after done chatting
private void closeCrap() {
    showMessage("\n closing connections...\n");
    ableToType(false);
    try {
        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// send message to a client
private void sendMessage(String message) {
    try {
        output.writeObject("SERVER - " + message);
        output.flush();
        showMessage("\nSERVER -" + message);
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        chatWindow.append("\n Error : can't send the message");
    }
}

// updates chat window

private void showMessage(final String text) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            chatWindow.append("" + text);
        }
    });
}

// allowing user to type stuff in the box

private void ableToType(final boolean tof) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            userText.setEditable(tof);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to put it in a different thread -  you can localize the thread to include only the startRunning method or what you want:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    Thread th=new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM EmplyeeInfo WHERE Username=? and password=?";
            PreparedStatement pst = dbconnection
                    .prepareStatement(query);

            pst.setString(1, textField_1.getText());
            pst.setString(2, passwordField_1.getText());

            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            int count = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                count++;
            }
            if (count == 1) {

                textField_1.setText("");
                passwordField_1.setText("");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Correct Username and Password");
                startRunning();

            } else {
                textField_1.setText("");
                passwordField_1.setText("");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong try again");
            }
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
  };
  th.start();
});
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why I needed the new thread and why my software freezes when I started the startrunning() method without the thread???